# Find string in combobox and show it

Tags: c#, wpf, list, combobox, selecteditem

I thought this would be easy, but now I don´t know how to do it exactly. 
In a WPF-application, i go from one window to another by clicking a contextmenu-item. My constructor for the new window looks like this:

```
    public Bearbeitung(int loginid, String art)
```

On the Window, there´s a checkbox filled with a list. What I want is, that the default selected item in my checkbox is `art`.
Ok, I checked if the String is in the list, but now I don´t know how to set it to the selecteditem in the combobox.

How can I manage this?

**EDIT:** I already tried

```
combobox.SelectedItem = art;
```

...that doesn´t work!

**EDIT2:**

Here´s the code:

```
      List<String> feld = new List<string>();
      feld = agrep.GetFelder(loginid);
      foreach (String s in feld)
      {
          cbFeld.Items.Add(s);
      }
      if (cbFeld.Items.Contains(art))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("It contains it");
           cbFeld.SelectedItem = art;
       }
```

The messagebox isn´t shown!

Comment: art is one of the existing item in your combobox ?

Comment: Well, if the message box isn't shown, that means that cbFeld.Items.Contains returned false and `cbFeld.SelectedItem = art` is never even executed! Are you *sure* that the combo box contains *exactly* the text from `art`?

Answer (score 2):

If the list items are just strings, you can simply do

```
myComboBox.SelectedItem = art;
```

Comment: @user896692: Do you get an error message? Are your ComboBox items really just strings? Maybe it would help if you showed the code you use to databind the combo box.

Comment: @user896692 you have the item art in your combobox ?

Comment: @user896692: That's surprising. Could you try the following? `myComboBox.SelectedItem = myComboBox.Items.Cast<string>.Where(x => x == art).Single();` Maybe it's because art is a different string object (containing the same value but with a different object identity)...

Answer (score 0):

*If* your `ComboBox` only contains **strings** you should be able to just set the `SelectedItem`

```
cb.SelectedItem = art;
```

If it does not only contain strings you might want to change that, e.g.

```
cb.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Item 1", "Item 2" };
```

If you have complex objects you will want to set the [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx) and [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cbFeld.Text = art;
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just solve it. The problem was, that when I give the string to the other window, a blank has been added. Thanks to you all!